# Screen resolution cannot be set to optimal (Dual boot Ubuntu 14.04-Windows 7)

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, xorg, resolution, xrandr

I recently made a partition in my Acer Aspire 5750G laptop to have Ubuntu 14.04 together with the original Windows 7. The original resolution (of the integrated screen) on Windows was 1366x768, but on Ubuntu I cannot get higher than 1024x768.

I have done some research on Google which has taken to modify `xorg.conf` and `monitors.xml` (they sometimes go back to their original values), now at least it tries other resolutions than 1024x768, though never higher than 1024x768.

When doing `cvt 1366 768` it gives me the modeline of 1368x768. Does it affect somehow that it is 1368 instead of 1366?

`xrandr` gives me the
`Failed to get size of gamma for output default` message. Is there a way to give a value for the default gamma, or do I need something else?

I have NVIDIA GeForce GT 520M, but when I try to use any of the NVIDIA controllers instead of the X Org "Nouveau", there is always a problem: after rebooting and logging in with my password, it only loads an "empty" desktop (no icons, no bar with the settings, date, time, etc., I can only move the mouse around the background).

Is it true that it is impossible for NVIDIA users to increase the resolution given by Ubuntu?
If not, how to proceed?

Comment: Try to search the proper drivers ? does the live cd works properly ?

Comment: The problem persists with live cd. What are the proper drivers? I tried NVIDIA already

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer. My problem was solved, but I did not fully understand why/how.

I answer my own question, hoping this may shed some light for others having similar issues, but they should make sure they can undo everything they try, as I cannot guarantee that this works for them

Boot choosing Linux Recovery mode (here the graphics will still look bad), download the NVIDIA drivers, install them, kill x and reboot choosing Linux (not the Recovery mode)